# How to add integer values in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I wanted to Query from two different tables, customers name, email with total amount they have spent. Each row in Query table would include the total amount spent. My code is this

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    email TEXT);
    
INSERT INTO customers (name, email) VALUES ("Doctor Who", "doctorwho@timelords.com");
INSERT INTO customers (name, email) VALUES ("Harry Potter", "harry@potter.com");
INSERT INTO customers (name, email) VALUES ("Captain Awesome", "captain@awesome.com");

CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    customer_id INTEGER,
    item TEXT,
    price REAL);

INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, item, price)
    VALUES (1, "Sonic Screwdriver", 1000.00);
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, item, price)
    VALUES (2, "High Quality Broomstick", 40.00);
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, item, price)
    VALUES (1, "TARDIS", 1000000.00);

select customers.name, customers.email, price as total_amount
    from customers
    left outer join orders
    on customers.id = orders.customer_id
    group by name
    order by total_amount desc;
```

The code should add two amount related to 'Doctor who' but it only show one value with highest amount. How do I add two values of 'Doctor who' and query in a single row ?

Oh! and I'm New to SQL and programming.

Comment: Add your expected result.

Comment: *The code should add two amount related to 'Doctor who'* Why? Where is the code that adds the amounts?

Comment: Why didn't you insert any ID for your customer?

Comment: @Rezu The customer id gets automatically generated by code when I used  ``` INSERT INTO..... ```

Comment: @forpas That is what I was trying to do which is why I asked the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I would say that this code shouldn't run at all -</strike>    whenever you do `group by` you should  do some kind of aggregation on all the columns in `select` that are not used in `group by` (except in MySQL which allows to put columns w/o aggregation which is equivalent to `first()`). In your case you want to sum all the orders, so that's what you do

```
select customers.name, customers.email, sum(price) as total_amount 
from ... 
group by customers.name, customers.email
```

I've added email to group by because name might be non-unique. However it would be even better to do `group by customers.id`. Also you will get `NULL` for customers w/o orders, so you might want to do `coalesce(sum(price),0)`

Comment: Aggregations are not necessary with `group by`.  Common, but definitely not necessary.  Other than that the answer is fine.

Comment: Is this MySQL specific? Does it picks the first value that it comes across?